# Does Hudson quiet period work in conjunction with SCM polling

Tags: hudson, jenkins

I've set up Hudson so it performs a build every hour. But I'd like it to wait a certain amount of time whenever there is "recent" checkin activity, in case there is more code about to be checked in related to this.

So I've set up the poll SCM option and the quiet period option but the build always seems to wait for the quiet period whenever there is an SCM change.

So I just wanted to know whether the SCM polling and quiet period can be used together in Hudson or is the quiet period superfluous when using a schedule.

Comment: There have been known problems related to quiet period vs polling , e.g https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-2180 .However this one should have already been fixed in 1.346, and it might not exactly be the issue what you're seeing.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that I am using Jenkins 1.427, which still exhibits the same behaviour I mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the quiet period should persist regardless of whether it starts by SCM change or by schedule. At least that's the  behaviour I have noticed on our build system.

Comment: If I had a job which was scheduled to run every hour and had a quiet period of 5 minutes, if it was due to execute at 2pm and the last checkin had been at 1:57 I'd expect it to run at 2:05 but if the last checkin was 1:52 I'd expect to to run at 2:00. Is this the sort of behaviour you are getting?

Comment: If you are polling for changes at 2:00pm - regardless of your time of checkin, I would expect your build to start at 2:05, since it polled at 2, and waited 5 minutes. If you are starting the build by timer at 2, your build should still start at 2:05, since it will wait 5 minutes. Is what you are seeing any different?

Comment: Yes, I get the same behaviour that you describe. I've had a few occasions where developers have made multiple checkins related to the same code change, either side of the hour mark which causes the build to break. But I suppose as long as they do atomic commits then it should not be an issue.